# Issue activating Nodemon

Tags: node.js, nodemon

I tried to activate nodemon inside a new server. Instead of activating it gave me an error.

```
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::3000
at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1279:14)
at listenInCluster (net.js:1327:12)
at Server.listen (net.js:1414:7)
at Function.listen (C:\Users\china\Desktop\my-express- 
server\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:618:24)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\china\Desktop\my-express- 
server\server.js:17:5) 
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)        
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
Emitted 'error' event at:
at emitErrorNT (net.js:1306:8)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:832:11)
at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

I expected it to activate inside my server and start monitoring for changes so I don't have to end and restart my server to see changes that I make.

Comment: Not a duplicate for  Node.js Port 3000 already in use but it actually isn't? This is a totally different problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
lsof -i:3000
kill -9 PID
```

This will kill the process i.e. node, that runs on port 3000. This issue generally comes up if you close the vscode without stopping the server, in the in build terminal.

Comment: This came up with the errors command not found and PID: arguments must be process or job IDs. Thank you for trying to help

Comment: after executing the first command there will be a list of process that will look something like this

`COMMAND  PID   USER   FD   TYPE  DEVICE  SIZE/OFF NODE NAME` ---->
`node     5805  xyz    12u  IPv6  63135    0t0     TCP  *:3000 (LISTEN)`

you have to replace the PID with a number that will come up in the 2nd column. :)

Comment: if it shows lsof `command not found`. Just hit an install with `sudo apt-get install lsof` @chinastar

Comment: And, I guess you can also kill it from task manager. `ctrl+alt+del`. And kill the node processes.

Answer (score 0):

kill node related processes, you can use `killall node`

Comment: if you want avoid this error, make sure to close correctly the application, you can use for this process.exit()